# plugins_url() incorrectly returning wp-include directory

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, plugins-url

I doubt there's a bug with `plugins_url()` but this is some odd behaviour I'm seeing.

I have the following in an activated plugin

```
function include_masonry() {
  wp_enqueue_script( 'masonry', plugins_url('js/masonry.min.js', __FILE__), array(), '3.2.1', true );
  wp_enqueue_script( 'my_init_script', plugins_url('js/my_init_script.js', __FILE__), array(), '1.0.0', true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'include_masonry' );
```

I arrived at this after using `get_template_directory_uri()` but decided against it since I want all plugin relevant js in the plugin folder.

This is the output in the footer:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/wp-includes/js/masonry.min.js?ver=3.1.2'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/wp-content/plugins/myplugin/js/my_init_script.js?ver=1.0.0'></script>
```

The second is fine but the first has 2 errors.

1) Why is it `?ver=3.1.2` when I specified 3.2.1? This is not a typo.

2) Why isn't it loading masonry.min.js from the plugin folder!? `plugins_url()` appears to return what `get_template_directory_uri()` returns, but just for `masonry.min.js`. I've hard refreshed, deleted the plugin file, reuploaded, swapped the `wp_enqueue_script` lines, and it always points to the wrong directory with the wrong version param.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Masonry is already registered by WordPress.

From `wp-includes/script-loader.php`:

```
// Masonry v2 depended on jQuery. v3 does not. The older jquery-masonry handle is a shiv.
// It sets jQuery as a dependency, as the theme may have been implicitly loading it this way.
$scripts->add( 'masonry', "/wp-includes/js/masonry.min.js", array(), '3.1.2', 1 );
$scripts->add( 'jquery-masonry', "/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.masonry$dev_suffix.js", array( 'jquery', 'masonry' ), '3.1.2', 1 );
```

So your first `wp_enqueue_script()` does not register masonry again. WordPress uses the already existing resource. `plugins_url()` is not related, its value isn’t even used.